# Is $(f(A))^c=f(A^c)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is $(f(A))^c=f(A^c)$ for any function?

I can only prove the forward direction:
$y\in(f(A))^c\implies y\notin f(A)\implies A$ has no $x$ such that $f(x)=y \implies f^{-1}(y)\notin A \implies f^{-1}(y)\in A^c$. But we know that $y\in f(f^{-1}(y))\in f(A^c)$ hence $y\in f(A^c)$ finally.

Is this proof lacking? Can anyone prove the other way. Thing is, I'm not even convinced this is true, but it says so in the slides I have.

Comment: Think you have a typo at the start, is $y \in f(A)$ should be $y \notin f(A)$

Comment: @ColmBhandal thanks, fixed

Comment: $f^{-1}(y)$ needn't be a single point, so you can't write "$f^{-1}(y)\notin A$". In general, it is a set, and it will in fact be the empty set if $y$ isn't in the image of $A$.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is only true if the function is bijective.

If $f$ is not surjective, $f(A)$ and $f(A^\complement)$ will not cover all of the codomain, so they are in particular not each other's complements.

If $f$ is not injective, there may be elements in common between $f(A)$ and $f(A^\complement)$, which again prevents them from being complements.

Comment: Thanks! I was kind of thinking in the same direction. I guess there is a mistake then.

Comment: what if f was replace by its inverse? I guess that would work

Comment: @ToniAz: Yes, it is true for $f:X\to Y$ that $f^{-1}(Y\setminus B)=X\setminus f^{-1}(B)$.